# Nexus S Text File Storage

Tags: android, text-files, nexus-s, android-file

I'm trying to read data from one of my sensors and write it to a text file. I'm using Eclipse, running my project on a Samsung Nexus S. I want to gather data, store it into a text file, and then access that file when I attach the Nexus S to my desktop via a USB cable.

I've seen a lot of explanations; but, they either explain how to save files to an SD card, which the Nexus S does not have, or they explain that Android does not allow users to access apllication data. I want to avoid rooting the phone.

There were two primary example methods that I have been toying with, keep in mind that one of the methods is commented out:

```
    public void appendLog(String text){
    //    try{
    //        FileOutputStream fout = openFileOutput("log.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    //        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fout);

    //        osw.write(text);
    //        osw.flush();
    //        osw.close();
    //    }
    //    catch(IOException e){
    //        
    //    }


  File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "log.txt");

  if(!logFile.exists()){
      try{
          logFile.createNewFile();
      }
      catch(IOException e){

      }
  }
  try{
      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
      buf.append(text);
      buf.newLine();
      buf.close();
  }
  catch(IOException e){

  }
  }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add the Android tag to this question.

Answer (score 2):

The Nexus S has an "/sdcard/" path just like the majority of the phones out there.  You can access it through `new File("/sdcard/");` but the preferred way to do it is with `new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());`.  That command gives you the external storage location, in case a particular phone does not have the "/sdcard" path as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).